# Enviar dados Para outra pagina

Tags: php

Há alguma forma de enviar dados com o php  através do POST; da mesma forma que é feita através do action da teg form.

Ou seja,enviar dados da pagina A para B e ser direcionado para a pagina B acessando esses dados.

Comment: Ser direcionado? O que quis dizer com isso?

Comment: vamos supor que tenha uma variável na tela A e ao clicar em um botão sou direcionado para atela B.Mas necessito de uma variável em B que estar em A . conheço algumas  forma de fazer isso que é via GET passando a variável pela URL ou por cookies.Minha pergunta é se da pra fazer por POST?

Comment: As páginas A e B estão no mesmo domínio?

Comment: sim.Estão dentro da mesma pasta.

Comment: o comportamento que quero é o mesmo obtido com action do form.

Comment: Então a resposta é: não será possível. Por que você precisa fazer isso? Está parecendo-me um problema XY.

Comment: Era uma duvida mesmo.Então as maneira pra fazer isso é através da URL por get ou usando cookies/sessão.

Comment: Impossível dizer sem conhecer o problema que está resolvendo. Pesquise mais sobre o protocolo HTTP e sobre ele não possuir estado. Dependendo do problema, podem existir outras inúmeras formas melhores de se resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um form full hidden:

Página A:

```
<b>Variável AA:</b>: <?= $aa ?><br />
<b>Variável AB:</b>: <?= $ab ?><br />
<form action="paginaB.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="variavel_aa value="<?= $aa ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="variavel_ab value="<?= $ab ?>">
   <input type="submit" value="PROXIMA">
</form>
```

Página B:

```
<b>Variável AA:</b>: <?= $POST['variavel_aa'] ?><br />
<b>Variável AB:</b>: <?= $POST['variavel_aa'] ?><br />
```

Comment: Mas neste caso não será o PHP que fará a requisição; será o próprio navegador, depois de tratar a resposta da página A.

Comment: Sim, eu utilizaria $_SESSION, mas ele falou "da mesma forma que é feita através do action da teg form"

Answer (score 1):

Tem como fazer isso com variáveis de sessão.
Na página A:

```
$_SESSION['variavel'] = 'Valor da variavel';
```

Na página B você captura o valor passado:

```
$var = $_SESSION['variavel'];
```

Só uma coisa: no início das páginas que irão usar isso deve-se colocar o seguinte:

```
session_start();
```